# .NET Container Stuck In Status Restarting For File Not Found Error

Tags: .net, docker, docker-compose

I'm starting some containers with docker compose but I face a strange error with one of them.

On my local machine (MacOS 14) I can start everything just fine, but on the production server (Ubuntu 22.04) the container keeps restarting throwing the following error:

```
File name: 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'
myapp-api-1  |    at Program.<Main>$(String[] args)
myapp-api-1  |    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
myapp-api-1  |    at Program.<Main>$(String[] args)
myapp-api-1  |    at Program.<Main>(String[] args)
myapp-api-1  | Unhandled exception. System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Some considerations:

- Nowhere in my code am I requiring to load `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions, Version=8.0.0.0`. In fact the only reference I have to that package is this: `<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions" Version="7.0.0" />`
- The container is always in status `restarting` making it impossible for me to enter and see what's going on
- The container image is defined as follows:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app

# Set the base image to the official .NET Core SDK image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY . .

# Restore dependencies
RUN dotnet restore "MyApp.Api/MyApp.Api.csproj"
RUN dotnet restore "MyApp.Application/MyApp.Application.csproj"
RUN dotnet restore "MyApp.Contracts/MyApp.Contracts.csproj"
RUN dotnet restore "MyApp.Domain/MyApp.Domain.csproj"
RUN dotnet restore "MyApp.Infrastructure/MyApp.Infrastructure.csproj"

# Build the app
RUN dotnet build "MyApp.sln" -c Release -o /app/build

# Publish the app
FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "MyApp.sln" -c Release -o /app/publish

# Set the final image
FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
COPY JsonSeed  ../JsonSeed
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MyApp.Api.dll"]
```

- This is the service definition in my `docker-compose-yml` file

```
  api:
    build: ./dotnet
    restart: always
    environment:
      DB_HOST: ${DB_HOST}
      DB_PORT: ${DB_PORT}
      DB_NAME: ${DB_NAME}
      DB_USERNAME: ${DB_USERNAME}
      DB_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
      MIGRATE: ${MIGRATE}
      PORT: ${PORT}
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:${PORT}:${PORT}"
    networks:
      - myapp-network
    depends_on:
      - db
```

Any idea what this could be or how to troubleshoot this?

Comment: Do you have any volume mappings when you run the container?

Comment: No, not on this one